# How can I ignore unused partials in handlebars precompilation?

Tags: gulp, dependencies, handlebars.js, precompile

I would like to collect only the depending partials of a single template. Or otherwise ignore unused partials. Because it is a large project with lots of templates/partials and dependencies it is not possible to do that by hand.

Example file and folder structure would be something like:

```
/sites/foo.hbs - includes {> partial1}
/sites/bar.hbs - includes {> partial2}
/partials/partial1.hbs
/partials/partial2.hbs
```

Now I would like to precompile **foo.hbs** only. For precompilation i have to configure **foo.hbs** as root and **/partials/*.hbs** as partials.

The precompilation should end up with the content of **foo.hbs** and **partial1.hbs** in a single file.

Is that possible with handlebars at all? Maybe with an existing gulp plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains a (somewhat) logical error.
Partials were initially intended to act as separate templates.
I guess your intentions are basically more syntactic sugar'ish, 
- as you wish to write your code separately though merge it on deployment (some people call that OCD, since it has no real benefit in terms of performance).

Anyhow.
You can run a node scripts that runs through your HBS's, locates partials, extracts them into their parent elements and outputs these final templates.

Take a look at this following answer -
[find files by extension, *.html under a folder in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460574/find-files-by-extension-html-under-a-folder-in-nodejs)