# fs.readdir ignore directories

Tags: javascript, node.js, readdir

I would like to scan the folder, but ignore all the folders/directories that are included in it. All I have in the (C:/folder/) are .txt files and other folders, I just want to scan the txt files, and ignore the folders.

```
app.get('/generatE', function (req, res) {
  const logsFolder = 'C:/folder/';
  fs.readdir(logsFolder, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send("[empty]");
      return;
     }
     var lines = [];
     files.forEach(function(filename) {
       var logFileLines = fs.readFileSync (logsFolder + filename, 'ascii').toString().split("\n");

       logFileLines.forEach(function(logFileLine) {


         if(logFileLine.match(/.*AUDIT*./)) {
           lines.push(logFileLine+'\n');
         }
       })
     })
```

Comment: Did you read this answers before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460574/find-files-by-extension-html-under-a-folder-in-nodejs

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use [`fs.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) or [`fs.readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) method with options `{ withFileTypes: true }` and then do filtration using [`dirent.isFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_dirent_isfile) (requires Node 10.10+).

### Sync version

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dirents = fs.readdirSync(DIRECTORY_PATH, { withFileTypes: true });
const filesNames = dirents
    .filter(dirent => dirent.isFile())
    .map(dirent => dirent.name);
// use filesNames
```

### Async version (with `async`/`await`, requires Node 11+)

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

async function listFiles(directory) {
    const dirents = await fs.readdir(directory, { withFileTypes: true });
    return dirents
        .filter(dirent => dirent.isFile())
        .map(dirent => dirent.name);
}
```

### Async version (with callbacks)

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir(DIRECTORY_PATH, { withFileTypes: true }, (err, dirents) => {
    const filesNames = dirents
        .filter(dirent => dirent.isFile())
        .map(dirent => dirent.name);
    // use filesNames
});
```

Comment: why is using dirents the proper way? whats wrong with using stats?

Comment: While the original question was regarding folders and in a windows enviroment I assume the solution is not the most correct one.
Unless there some sane reason to not do it this way (please tell).Even if folders might give you problems, but I promise you program will be just as supprised and cranky when it come across /dev/null a socket or something else non file

const filesNames = dirents
    .filter(dirent => dirent.isFile())
    .map(dirent => dirent.name);

Comment: Totally agree with @Griffin, I've just run into a situation that the directory contains several symlinks `dirent.isSymbolicLink() === true`, on macOS, when the source of the symlink is a file, everything works as expected, but once it's a dir, I get an error of `Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read`, I have to filter them out via recursive calls.

Comment: `when the source of the symlink is ... a dir ... have to filter them out via recursive calls`  ---- 
Actually `fs.stat()` is more convenient for this use case, which follows symlink automatically.

Answer (score 3):

**Please See diralik's answer as it is more complete: my answer only works if ALL filenames contain a '.txt' extension.**

why not just filter out files that end in ".txt"?

```
var fs = require("fs")
fs.readdirSync("./").filter(function(file) {
    if(file.indexOf(".txt")>-1)console.log(file)
})
```

I should have added previously that to get an array of these files you need to return them to an array as shown below.

```
var fs = require("fs")
let text_file_array = fs.readdirSync("./").filter(function(file) {
    if(file.indexOf(".txt")>-1) return file;
})
```

Comment: or `.filter(f => f.includes(".txt"))` with ES6

Comment: minus one because not working in generic case (when file extenstion is unknown)

Comment: also another minus one because it will not work for files without extension like DockerFile

Comment: I have amended my answer with a warning of the possible side-effects.

Comment: Also does not work when a directory name ends with `.txt`.