# Node JS filesystem module reading directory exclude files

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, fs

I have some Node JS javascript code that reads folders inside of a directory, however it's currently reading folders and files, and I just need it to read folders and can't figure out what U'm missing:

```js
router.get('/check', (req, res) => {

  fs.readdir('./directory', function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ error: { status: 500, message: 'error' } })
      return
    }

    console.log('success')
  })

})
```

I was thinking about doing something like `files[0].length > X` for instance to only show names that contain more than X characters, or filter out file extensions etc, I ideally just need directories since I have a `.empty` file inside.

Comment: Maybe this answer suit your need https://stackoverflow.com/a/52243773/8710163

Answer (score 0):

You can check reference on documentation. `readdir()` will return contents of the directory. You need to filter folders or files. Simply you can call and create new array `files.filter(fileName => fs.statSync(path + fileName).isFile()`.

[ref](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback)

**Update**

Given sample code will filter files and folders into to seperated variables. You can implement into your project.

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    
    const dir = fs.readdirSync(__dirname);
    const folders = dir.filter(element => fs.statSync(path.join(__dirname, element)).isDirectory());

    const files = dir.filter(element => fs.statSync(path.join(__dirname, element)).isFile);
    console.log('folders', folders, 'files', files);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I've added: `const folders = files.map(fileName => fs.statSync(path + fileName).isFile())`, and I have a folder called `test`, getting: `no such file or directory, stat '[object Object]test'` lol

Comment: @RyanHolton I editted my answer and added a sample code