# Using webpack and html-webpack-plugin to output many html files

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, templating

I'm using webpack to output JS, SASS/CSS and HTML and some other operations, including babel.

I also have a series of static HTML files that have several operations run on them as well. While most examples show how to output one, two or three HTML files, using this:

```
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'html/index.html',
        template: 'html/index.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'html/about.html',
        template: 'html/about.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'html/settings.html',
        template: 'html/settings.html'
    }),
```

What if I can't predict how many pages there will be? What if there's 40+? How can I approach this better?

Still relatively new to webpack, but I've had experience with with gulp and grunt.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

1. Find the files with the extension that you want.
2. Create new HtmlWebpackPlugin object configuration for each one.

To find the files with the extension, we can use the function [findFilesInDir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25478516/6105824) adapted by the user Nicolas:

```
...

let findFilesInDir = require('./findFilesInDir.js')

let templateFilesConf = findFilesInDir('src/html', '.html')
 .map((templateFileName) =>  
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     filename: templateFileName,
     template: templateFileName
   })
)

let webpackConf = {
  entry: './path/to/my/entry/file.js',
  ...
  plugins : [...]
}  

webpackConf.plugins = webpackConf.plugins.concat(templateFilesConf)

module.exports = webpackConf
```